# Cannot move mailitem after reading properties

Tags: vba, outlook

In VBA for Outlook I wrote a routine which should move certain incoming emails to another folder.

When I read any property, besides `Class`, from the incoming MailItem (to determine whether or not it should be moved) I can't move it.

Error:

> can't move item(s)

```vb
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objMyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMyInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objNewMailItems = objMyInbox.Items
Set objMyInbox = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim strSubject As String
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub  
    strSubject = Item.Subject
    Item.Move objNS.PickFolder
Exit Sub
```

It works when I delete the line `strSubject = Item.Subject’ but I need to know something of that MailItem to determine whether it should be moved and where.

This depends on values stored in a database but that seems irrelevant when I can't move the mail after reading the 'subject' or any other other property besides `Class`.

I tried making a copy of the `MailItem` to read values from, but as soon as I make a copy I get the error when trying to move the `MailItem`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points that must be addressed before. The `Subject` property is not the problem I suppose.

First, the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) methods accepts an instance of the Folder class, so instead of calling the `PickFolder` method inplace:

```
Item.Move objNS.PickFolder
```

I'd suggest calling it outside of the ItemAdd event handler and use the object, for example:

```
myItem.Move myDestFolder
```

Second, I don't think the `ItemAdd` event is the appropriate place for calling the `Move` method. I'd recommend using the `NewMailEx` event handler instead. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.  The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - thank you! Preserving the MailItem.EntryID and passing it to a different routine where I used the method GetItemFromID() to further handle the mail did the trick.
By the way, I noted by accident that setting, in the Trust centre, "Enable all macro's" also made the error disappear. Odd, isn't it? But anyway, that wouldn't be an acceptable solution.